# Android display text language wrong on some part

Tags: java, android

On the app, sometime will display wrong text language such as one activity will display "zh_tw" and "en" together when change the app language. But sometime it has not the problem.

the below is the change language code:

```
public static void setApplicationLanguage(Context context, Locale locale) {

    Resources resources = context.getApplicationContext().getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration config = resources.getConfiguration();
    config.locale = locale;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        LocaleList localeList = new LocaleList(locale);
        LocaleList.setDefault(localeList);
        config.setLocales(localeList);
        context.getApplicationContext().createConfigurationContext(config);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
    }
    resources.updateConfiguration(config, dm);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    finishAffinity();
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

I google search cannot find any solution or some like situation. Thank.

Answer (score 0):

For this, call a function in your LocaleeManager class from class(Base class) extending Application class
In your Application class,

```
  @Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(LocaleManager.setLocale(base));
}
```

In your Locale manager. This code should not have a problem relating  API change for local. It works for me

```
private static Context updateResources(Context context, String language) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(language);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Resources res = context.getResources();
    Configuration config = new Configuration(res.getConfiguration());
    config.setLocale(locale);
    context = context.createConfigurationContext(config);
    return context;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: I already try your code but not work.
Have you other idea and suggestion?
Thank!

Comment: this is really late. Are you using application context or activity? if you are using the application context then you have to restart the whole application. if you are using activity context and then your app is made of multiple activities then you should change it to application context and restart the whole application. if you are using single activity then activity context should work.

Comment: Thanks for response. the context is from activity and multiple activitys. i will try change the context from application.

Comment: ok. Also, update Appcompat to the latest version. I think I forgot to explain the context in my previous response. If you are using the application context to get resources and but after changing the language you only restart activity then only the strings in your layout file will get translated.  Because the application is never restarted and the application context is the same so the resources will not get updated.

Comment: Thanks for explaining.
It look like not any problem.
But in my project, I will clear the stack after change language each times. Such as “  i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK” but I cannot use pendingintent, it will crash each times.